# set new document library unsearchable

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Is there any action/ way to set new document library/list to unsearchable ? because i does not want the new document library/ list to appear in the search result.
Thanks.

other information:
i using sharepoint designer 2013

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to your List or Document library settings > Advanced settings

2) Set Search option to "No" to exclude document library or list from search in SharePoint, as seen below.

[image]

3) Press OK at the bottom.

4) Now the document library will not be available in search

Comment: thanks @Gautam. I need include it in the workflow. Do you know how to apply in workflow ?

Comment: can you elaborate ? I dont get it. What do you mean by apply in workflow ? The above steps can be done in the browser itself.

Comment: i create the document library by workflow and it need to be set unsearchable.

Comment: you can follow this link - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-list-using-http-web-service-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/ , in the list/doc library creation parameters, you can set NoCrawl to true. Not 100% sure if it will work or not , else you can use event receiver or console application to set this property.

Answer (score 0):

- Open your document library via the browser.
- From the above ribbon > select Library Settings.
- Click on Advanced Settings,
- In Search Section Select **No** to `disallow items from this document library to appear in search results`

[image]

**[Update]**

Based on your new requirement in comments, you can't set this option via Workflow, but You can develop an event receiver on list/library added and set `List.NoCrawl=False`.

```
SPList list = ...    
list.NoCrawl = true;    
list.Update();
```

Meanwhile, you can achieve that Via PowerSehll

```
$List.NoCrawl = $true
```

Comment: Thanks @M.Qassas . But I want to include it in workflow. Do you have any idea how to apply it in workflow ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but you can achieve that via PowerShell or event receiver on list added let me update my answer with that